# MVC 5 : Is using Attribute on Async action make it Synchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've create an attribute called Log, which is Synchronous ( you cannot create async attributes in MVC 5 ), is it making my action synchronous ( Sync over Async antipattern )?
Here is the code:

```
[Log]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't. That's not how attributes work.

Comment: Thanks Pauwelyn for your answer, can you please add more details how it works when you call an attribute over an async action

Comment: Can you include the relevant bits of your `LogAttribute`. FilterAttributes are a little bit different but still shouldn't affect the asynchronicity of your action.